# Installing Module in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I've uploaded a new unzipped module folder into site/modules directory through ftp. But it is not shown in admin panel module lists from where I can configure it. Please help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I've uploaded a new unzipped module folder into site/modules directory
>   through ftp

To be precise, you have to upload the module to sites/all/modules folder. Say you upload Views module, then there should be a file called /sites/all/modules/views/views.info. Not sites/modules/views.info . You'll have to create a folder called "modules" if this is your first contributed module installation

By default, Drupal clears module caches when you access modules list (D7: admin/modules , D6: admin/build/modules)

Make sure that you search the modules list well. it's long one so most likely that you miss it unless you know it's human-friendly name.

D7 only supports D7 modules, D6 only supports D6 modules,...

Comment: my site is of D6 and I've used D6 module. I think the problem is permission related. how I'll make the /all/modules folder to 755 permission level?? I'm using windows7

Comment: Umh.. I have never faced a permissions problem though. You can do permissions change with FileZilla anyway.
Can you make sure that the .info file of the module you are using is placed correctly as above ?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... You said you uploaded the module, but it's not appearing in configuration pages. Sorry if I don't understand what you are explaining and it's obvious but probably you did not enable the module (or a module that shows the UI's of this module) on admin/build/modules

Hope that helps!